# How To Check if locally created ID does not exist in Firestore database, if it does, regerate ID and try again until Document doesn't alreadt exist

Tags: swift, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to create a unique identifier for a document in a Firestore database. This id is a session ID that needs to be unique, locally generated and not loads of characters long (like the automatically generated one). I am trying to write code that checks to see if the document with that ID already exists. If it does not then set the SessionID, if it does exist then randomly generate another ID and perform the check again. This should loop continue until no document exists with that ID and then the session can initialize. The issue is that I can't put this in a while loop as Firebase connectivity cannot handle this. Does anyone have any suggestions, or another way to achieve the same thing? Thank you in advance.

```
func setsessionid () {

        sessionid = randomAlphaNumericString(length: 6)

        let docRef = self.db.collection("strokedata").document(self.sessionid!)

        docRef.getDocument { (document, error) in
            if let document = document, document.exists {


            } else {

                let currentsession = self.sessionid!
                self.sessionID.text = "SESSION ID: \(currentsession)"

                let user = Auth.auth().currentUser
                if let user = user {
                        self.userid = user.uid
                }

                print("Document does not exist")

            }
    }
```

Comment: why don't you want to use the automatically generated one?

Comment: because it is very long and I want to use a shortened string because the two iOS devices are going to share the same session and I don't want the user to have to type in a long string. I just need to make sure that two sessions with the same unique ID don't get created (I know the odds are slim).